# Disclosure and Barring Service (DBS) UK - Meaning

Tags: meaning

My question is simple (hope not too simple):

Why this organization has chosen this name?  - DISCLOSURE AND BARRING SERVICE 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disclosure_and_Barring_Service

*DBS enables organisations in the public, private and voluntary sectors to make safer recruitment decisions by identifying candidates who may be unsuitable for certain work, especially that involve children or adults, and provides wider access to criminal record information through its disclosure service for England and Wales.*

I know **disclosure** means *to reveal* and **Barring** probably means *to exclude* (in this context). Does it simply mean *a service that reveals information and exclude candidates based on that information*?

Answer (score 1):

It seems straightforward enough. Part of their function is to keep a register of individuals 'Barred' from specific professions or roles (for example sex offenders, via court rulings). They also offer the 'Disclosure' of that sensitive information to those who have good reason to see it, for example potential employers.

Comment: I was confused by the term 'barring' because **barring service** seems to mean _a service that bars_, and not only a service that 'keep a register of individuals barred'.

Comment: well strictly I suppose in this case they do the actual barring, in that even a convicted criminal would not be barred *until* they appear on the register, by definition.